# CRM: Xrm Javascript MultiRetrieve for delete

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, xrm

I have two entities (which we will call `A` and `B`), among which there is a many-to-many relationship. So I manually created a third entity. `A` records can be contained in a `subgrid` of `B`. There are multiple instances of `B`, so, records of `A` can be contained in multiple instances of `B`. My goal is to make it possible to delete instances of `A` contained in a particular `B` only if `A` are not referenced by other `B`.

I am forced to use JavaScript with Xrm and fetchXml.

Comment: Hi Enrico, you may want to review [Ask], and provide the code for what you have tried so far.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you needed to manually create a third entity? Dynamics CRM supports many-to-many relationships (between entities A and B)

Comment: Your question seems to be vague. You mentioned you are creating a third entity but further that was not mentioned anywhere. Assume that is not valid here. But one doubt here is why can't you try this using out of the box CRM relationships. If you have your relationship proper you should be able to achieve this without any code. Referntial Restrict Delete or Configurable cascading (restrict delete). Hope that helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

If i am not miss understand your question, you mean you want to check the relationship before the entity record delete operation.
I think this operation should be done by **Plugin** not **JS**, because the delete operation will only trigger the plugin as i know.

1. get the delete entity record by image.
2. check the relationship for your A and B entity.
3. delete the record relate.

But i strongly suggest you finish your job as @Renjith says that "Referntial Restrict Delete or Configurable cascading (restrict delete)", this function need no code.